# VBA Excel SQL Query to update a field with more than 255 characters

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

looking for a bit of help/advice please.

**The Problem:** I am trying to run an SQL query in VBA Excel to update an Excel Spreadsheet (.xlsx) column/field with a value that is greater than 255 characters but I am receiving the following error:

```
The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add.
Try inserting or pasting less data.
```

**The Code:** My connection string is as follows:

```
    Sub Open_Conn(strDb As String)
On Error GoTo conError
    Debug.Print (Time() & " - Connecting to: " & strDb)
    Set CON = New ADODB.Connection
    CON.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    CON.Open "Data Source=" & strDb & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes"""
    Debug.Print (Time() & " - Connected")
    Exit Sub
conError:
    MsgBox ("There was an error processing the connection: " & strSQL &
    vbNewLine & Error(Err))
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

and my sql query code is:

```
Public Sub AddChangeRecord(ByVal strFieldName As String, ByVal strFieldValueNew As String, ByVal strFieldValueOld As String)

Dim strSQL As String
Dim strProgramNo, strUserID, strUpdateDate As String

strProgramNo = frmMain.tbProgramNumberPD.Value
strUserID = Environ("Username")
strUpdateDate = Format(Date, "dd mmm yy")

strSQL = "Insert Into [tblAuditLog$] (Program_No, UserID, UpdatedField, UpdateDate, OldValue, NewValue) " _
& "Values ('" & strProgramNo & "', '" & strUserID & "', '" & strFieldName & "', '" & strUpdateDate & "', '" & strFieldValueOld & "', '" & strFieldValueNew & "')"

Call Open_Conn(strDb)
Call Open_RS(strSQL)

Call Close_Conn

End Sub
```

**The Background:** I have tried some suggestions that I have found online already including setting the maxscanrow variable in the connection string and making sure my first row contains default values of the specific length (so the columns first value contains a random string that is longer than 255 characters). I have also read that it may be possible to change registry keys but I am looking to distribute this to other machines and changing the reg keys of each machine is not possible unfortunately. Does anyone have any more possible suggestions for me to try?

As always thank you in advance for any help/advice.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that there are already existing around 16 records in the table with the column in question having different value lengths.

Comment: Are `strProgramNo` and `strUserID` strings in the db? Check your db settings to make sure you've got the correct data types and there isn't a data conversion issue going on.

Comment: Hi Tom, checked the data types and they all look ok from what I can see, from what I have learned excel will automatically assign a data type to the column based on the first x amount of rows (8 or 16? I have read conflicting info on the exact amount) but my data is of varied length (not always over 255)

Comment: Do any of the columns in `SQL` have any length limitations on them. Is `SQL` expecting to only get string values then? (`VARCHAR`)

Comment: Not sure how to check this, sorry. As far as I know I have not put into place any restrictions of any kind, I wasn't aware this was an option in Excel? (Edit: other than data validation text lengths sorry - which I have not touched though)

Comment: When the database table was set up each field would have been given data types. If you are trying to feed one with the incorrect data type or too larger data it will throw an error. This is not as much Excel as the SQL side that you're posting to

Comment: My database is just an excel .xlsx file Tom, I didn't really go through any setup stages when I created it, just added a sheet and named it then added my columns, have I missed a step out when I first created it maybe?